# Azure Cosmos db Unique Key on collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create an unique key for an whole collection in Cosmos DB.
So not unique per _pk.

I read this article but here it only writes about Unique key per partition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys.

I Googled a lot but I can't find any result about a uk on collection. Is this even possible? And if it is, is there any documentation about it?

Comment: With unique key I mean a field like username that has to be unique, this field is not going to be the partitionkey. But in the same collection there must be possible to store different objects without an username. I hope this makes it clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys#using-unique-keys) about cosmos db unique key is clearly stated.

> I am trying to create an unique key for an whole collection in Cosmos
>   DB.

Unique keys must be defined when the container is created, and the unique key is scoped to the partition key.

> In the same collection there must be possible to store different
>   objects without an username.

Sparse unique keys are not supported. If values for some unique paths are missing, they are treated as a special null value, which takes part in the uniqueness constraint.

If you do want to make the `username` field unique in the whole collection across the partitions and even null value is permitted, I think you need to check the uniqueness by yourself before inserting documents into cosmos db.I suggest you using [pre-triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-pre-triggers) to do the check.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Indeed I already was afraid that this is impossible in Cosmos DB.